# Is it an antipattern to set state based on URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 views: stream, playlist, and profile.
Each view requires different buttons (minor differences), but the components do not care about the distinction overall. They continue to retrieve and present data normally.

There is not enough distinction to create different components, i just need a state variable to change the buttons.

Here's the problem: the only way to get the state variable is either a.) in window.location.pathname, or b.) in props passed by react router, which is then made available via the context api. Is one solution better than another? Are they both incorrect for a professional app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with changing your single component depending on what is present in your url. This is a great use case for [URL parameters](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params).

**Example**

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  const { params } = props.match;
  const { pathParameter } = params;

  if (pathParameter === "home") {
    return <div> Welcome to my home page </div>;
  } else if (pathParameter === "about") {
    return <div> This is the about me page </div>;
  } else {
    return <div> This is a third option </div>;
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        <Link to="/blog">Blog</Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/:pathParameter" component={MyComponent} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```